# Can install4j update the xml files in the .war or .jar during 'Installer->Installation'?

Tags: install4j

This question is in regards to install4j 4.2.8.

We can get the users' information from their input.
It's easy to update the xml files with users' input.

But is it possile to replace the xml files in the war/jar file with above modified xml files during installation?
Is there any action can do this job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to extract the WAR file to a temporary directory with a "Extract ZIP file" action, run the "Replace text in XML files" action on the XML file and use a "Create a ZIP" file action to overwrite the original WAR file.

---

**Update for install4j 6.1+**

Since install4j 6.1, there is a "Modify ZIP file" action that can modify files inside a ZIP file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there is not "Extract ZIP file" action or "Create a ZIP" action in install4j 4.2.8. How can I get these actions?

Comment: OK, I missed the version number. These actions are only available in install4j 5.x.