# install4j 6.0.4 - Cannot create ZIP file

Tags: zip, install4j

I'm using install4j 6.0.4 and I need to update content of one WAR file. Regarding to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410396/can-install4j-update-the-xml-files-in-the-war-or-jar-during-installer-instal), I configured following actions as part of "Installation" screen:

1. ExtractZipFileAction - works as expected, unzipped correctly
2. ModifyTextFileAction - works as expected, file content is changed
3. CreateZipFileAction - **no new WAR file is created and next action fails**

**But all three actions are marked as successful in log file:**

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.ExtractZipFileAction [ID 13956]: Execute action
       Property mode: 666
       Property dirMode: 777
       Property zipFile: myApplication.war
       Property showProgress: false
       Property fileFilter: null
       Property destinationDirectory: temp_war
       Property rollbackSupported: true
       Execute action successful after 30363 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.text.ModifyTextFileAction [ID 12713]: Execute action
       Property searchValue: mySomething1
       Property logReplacement: true
       Property replaceValue: mySomething2
       Property encoding: null
       Property escapeForPropertyFile: false
       Property failIfNoReplacement: true
       Property files: [temp_war\myFile.txt]
       Property rollbackSupported: true
       Backing up C:\Program Files\MyApplication\temp_war\myFile.txt
       Execute action successful after 16 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.CreateZipFileAction [ID 13957]: Execute action
       Property zipFile: myApplication-new.war
       Property recursive: true
       Property addTopLevelDirectoriesToRelativePath: true
       Property showFileNames: true
       Property showProgress: true
       Property files: [temp_war, myAnotherFile.txt]
       Property fileFilter: null
       Property directoryFilter: null
       Property rollbackSupported: true
       Execute action successful after 16721 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.InstallationScreen [ID 8]: Rollback barrier reached
       command: move 1 screens, executing actions, checking condition
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.MoveFileAction [ID 5318]: Execute action
   Property shared: false
   Property destinationFile: myDestinationFolder
   Property mode: 644
   Property uninstallMode: Always
   Property overwriteMode: Always
   Property directoryMode: 755
   Property triggerReboot: false
   Property recursive: true
   Property delay: false
   Property showProgress: true
   Property showFileNames: false
   Property directoryFilter: null
   Property files: [myApplication-new.war]
   Property fileFilter: null
   Property rollbackSupported: true
   The file "C:\Program Files\MyApplication\myApplication-new.war" does not exist
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.MoveFileAction [ID 5318]: Execute action not successful after 0 ms
```

Also, I'm not able to update existing WAR file. I specified it in property 'zipFile' in CreateZipFileAction, this action was again marked as successful but WAR file was not updated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to update to install4j 6.1 which has a "Modify ZIP file" action which makes this much easier.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that "Modify ZIP file" will simplify it. But I prefer some solution/workaround for version 6.0.4. Especially when we have license only for this version.

Comment: Based on a fact that [version 6.1 contains a lot of changes](https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/install4j/changelog.html#6.1) and current version 6.0.4 seems stable for us, we did a workaround a implemented static Java function to compress appropriate files to ZIP archive. Anyway, thank you Ingo for your help!